# Starting a new conversation thread via content provider

Tags: java, android, sms, android-contentprovider

Before we begin, I know that the SMS content provider is undocumented. I know using it is not recommended.

Since I'm using it anyways, I would like some help achieving one of my goals.
I currently am able to add and remove messages without a problem. The issue comes in after I have deleted an entire thread and try to restore it. The messages are in the database, (If i attempt to add them again, I get an error,

`android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: PRIMARY KEY must be unique (code 19)`

so I know that the messages are there.) but if i open up a messages app, they do not display.

If I delete all but one message from the thread, the restored messages display back in their thread just fine. Any ideas on why I am unable to create a new message thread?

```
Uri allSmsUri = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
```

.

```
getContentResolver().delete(allSmsUri, "_id = ?", new String[] { m.get_id() });
```

.

```
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("person", m.getPerson());
        values.put("_id", m.get_id());
        values.put("thread_id", m.getThread_id());
        values.put("body", m.getBody());
        values.put("address", m.getAddress());
        values.put("read", m.getRead());
        values.put("date", m.getDate());
        values.put("type", m.getType());
        values.put("date_sent", m.getDate_sent());
        values.put("protocol", m.getProtocol());
        values.put("status", m.getStatus());
        values.put("reply_path_present", m.getreply_path_present());
        values.put("subject", m.getSubject());
        values.put("service_center", m.getservice_center());
        values.put("locked", m.getLocked());
        values.put("error_code", m.getError_code());
        values.put("seen", m.getSeen());

getContentResolver().insert(allSmsUri, values);
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably because when you "delete" a message thread, it's marked as deleted in the SMS internals, but not actually removed from the underlying database. When you try to add the thread back to the provider, the _ID value conflicts with the row that's still in the database.

In general, it's a really *bad* ("bad bad bad bad bad, not good" - Detritus, the troll, *Men At Arms*) idea to insert or delete data from bundled content providers using ContentResolver methods. Nearly all of these content providers have a complex internal state management system that you're bound to screw up if you try to "roll your own" process.

Instead, you should stick to doing inserts and deletes using intents. The benefits are:

- The bundled app containing the content provider handles the state management for you.
- You can't make mistakes by trying to do something that the provider doesn't support
- You get temporary permission to modify the provider, so you don't have to request the
  permission in your own app. Users like that.

If you must go ahead and do it yourself, then read the documentation carefully, including the javadoc. If you don't see an answer to your question, you should assume that someone deliberately did not want you to do something. You're free to read the open source, but you're on your own.

Do I also have to point out that using an undocumented, unsupported API guarantees that your app will break in the future?

Comment: I'm well aware of the downsides, which is why i mentioned it. Currently there is no way to achieve what Im trying to do with the intent system. I know it is possible, https://github.com/jberkel/sms-backup-plus this app does it and does it (AFAIK) the same as i, inserts and deletes.